# Expression UK radio hosts and MCs use to shout out to friends/fans

Tags: british-english, spoken-english, slang, understanding

I notice this mainly in drum 'n' bass/grime/dubstep radio shows from UK where an MC or the host frequently talks over the tune. Similar to terms like 'shout out to xxx' or 'big up xxx', where xxx denotes a fellow artist/listener/twitter user, they greet them with an expression that sounds to me like 'anti', 'n-type' or 'entire'.

What are they actually saying, what does it mean, where does it originate from?

Example: https://youtu.be/U6mIumn0Fck?t=15m42s

I assume this is urban UK slang because I haven't noticed it anywhere else.

Comment: Okay, I'm a native American English speaker, and I'm curious what they're saying too. :-)

Comment: It sounds like "an ta" to me, best guess: "And to..."

Comment: I think he is saying: [we are] anti-tommy guns. I don't think it is a greeting. Of course, I could be wrong. And they seem to be anti- a bunch of things.

Comment: Along the lines of what @Doarn was suggesting, maybe they're saying "And to my..." and combining "to my" into "ty"?

Comment: There seem to be two things: one is: [**going out] ta [to]** somebody, and the other really sounds like: anti-something. It's just squished together.

Comment: I'm a native English speaker from the UK and I'd say I'm pretty good with my slang but I have no clue what they are saying.

Comment: @L Smith Well, there it is. :)

Comment: They are talking in "Jafaican". This is a dialect ("fake Jamaican") used by many younger people of all ethnic backgrounds in London and also middle class white people (mainly male) who want to appear hip. My impression is that Jafaican is not their normal mode of speech. This dialect is said to be on the way to replacing the "Cockney" dialect that is stereotypically associated with working-class Londoners. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicultural_London_English

Comment: If you think the fact of the host talking over the tune changes the meaning of what the host says, please explain how.

Quite separately, “shout out to…” means “say ‘Hello’ to…” which is very different from anything like “big up…” which broadly means “to make much of…” not similar at all.

For another thing, to “shout out to…” has been in use for 50-odd years; to “big up” not much more than 10.

By the way, when did you last here anyone on radio referred to as an "MC", please?

Answer (score 1):

I have to concur with those saying he is shortening "and going out to" down to simply "andta".. it almost seems as if he is reading his fb and tweeter feeds while that dude is ripping it and maybe he is shouting out to his live feed watchers?